# ALSA/Pulse Audio

Tags: bluetooth

What is the difference between ALSA and Pulse Audio  ?

What is the use of ALSA and Pulse Audio as applied to A2DP streaming when the my device works as a sink device?

Thanks, Yogesh

Answer (score 1):

ALSA is a driver and API to interface directly with the sound device. It allows low-level reading, writing and device control, as well as some MIDI support. Pulse Audio is a sound server which can use ALSA to access the sound card and also provide network audio and more advanced software mixing/scheduling.

I do not know much about Pulse Audio's implementation of A2DP (if any), however this is not something that ALSA is designed to support.

J